# Quantitative method to select tactical bands for asset allocation

Tags: asset-allocation, tactical-asset-allocation

Do you know a study with a methodology for selecting tactical bands (or the allowed deviation from a strategic asset allocation)? Thanks

Comment: First search result from google

http://www.choateinvestmentadvisors.com/uploads/103/doc/Tactical%20Bands00.pdf

Comment: 4th results: https://www.alexandria.unisg.ch/export/DL/51978.pdf‎

Comment: Re 1st search result from Google: The paper just says that Choate uses some quantitative rules to define the tactical bands, but they don't explain what those rules are.

Comment: @Victor I understand that it has been some time since June 2014, but did you end up finding approaches for the selection of trading bands?